# Can't create 2 independent Observables with forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs5, angular2-http

I have a function that takes a ID as parameter and makes HTTP calls, depending on the ID. It returns a Observable. I expected the calls with different parameters to be completely independent, but they influence each other.

I use
RxJS 5.0.0-beta.2
Angular 2.0.0-beta.7 for the http calls
Typescript 1.8.2

**Code:**

```
getCharacterDetails (id : number) : Observable<CharacterDetails> {
    let keys : SpreadsheetKeys = this.characters[id];
    if (!keys) {
        return null;
    }

    let frontUrl : string = `${BASE_URL}/${CELLS}/${keys.spreadsheetKey}/${keys.frontWorksheetKey}/${OPTIONS}`;
    let backUrl : string = `${BASE_URL}/${CELLS}/${keys.spreadsheetKey}/${keys.backWorksheetKey}/${OPTIONS}`;

    return Observable.forkJoin(

        this.http.get(frontUrl).map(response => response.json()),
        this.http.get(backUrl).map(response => response.json()))

        .map((response : any[]) => {

            let character : CharacterDetails = EMPTY_MODEL;

            console.log(JSON.stringify(character)); // The 1st console.log

            applyFrontSheetToCharacter(response[0], character);
            applyBackSheetToCharacter(response[1], character);

            console.log(JSON.stringify(character)); // The 2nd console.log

            return character;
        });
}
```

**Expected behavior:**

I call
`getCharacterDetails(1).subscribe((details) => { this.details = details }));`
The 1st console.log prints my EMPTY_MODEL.
The 2nd console.log prints the character model for ID 1.

then I call
`getCharacterDetails(2).subscribe((details) => { this.details = details });`
The 1st console.log prints my EMPTY_MODEL.
The 2nd console.log prints the character model for ID 2.

**Actual behavior:**

I call
`getCharacterDetails(1).subscribe((details) => { this.details = details }));`
The 1st console.log prints my EMPTY_MODEL.
The 2nd console.log prints the character model for ID 1.

then I call 
`getCharacterDetails(2).subscribe((details) => { this.details = details });`
**The 1st console.log prints the character model for ID 1.** <- Problem
The 2nd console.log prints the character model for ID 2.

**Why are the 2 calls not completely independent? How does the 2nd call even know about the data from the first call?**

Comment: Could you add a prefix in your console.log? Something like `console.log(number + ': '+JSON...);` To be sure ;-)

Comment: I added the ID in front of to the console.log like you suggested. Nothing actually changed, the console logs now show:`1: {EMPTY_MODEL}` then `1: {data for ID 1}` then `2: {data for ID1}` then `2: {data for ID2}`. What result where you hoping for?

Comment: I don't think this is related to the forkJoin, it sounds to be the way you may be handling `EMPTY_MODEL`.

Comment: Oh my god, you are so right :|   What a stupid oversight -.-  What's the "best" way to define an empty model so I can initialize variable with it? The EMPT_MODEL looked like this `{name: '', age: 0, ...}`

Comment: I just made a getEmptyModel methode that returns a CharacterDetails object fully initialized with "empty" data (like empty strings and zeros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was simply that I completely misused the EMPTY_MODEL. It was basically a class-wide variable that I was editing in the .map() function.
A silly mistake that was unrelated to RxJS, Angular or HTTP